# Как движение по синусоиде Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть код который заставляет двигать объект по синусоиде. Я вижу что оно зависит от времени.
При зажатии пробела куб останавливает свое движение. Но после отжатия он появляется в другом месте. Можно ли это как то решить или нужен новый скрипт ?

```
public float frequency = 20f;

public float magnitude = 0.5f;

Vector3 pos;

void Start ()
{
    pos = transform.position;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    if(!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        transform.position = pos + transform.up * Mathf.Sin(Time.time * frequency) * magnitude;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Time.time` - это время в которое работает приложение. Как следствие оно продолжает тикать невзирая на то, зажать пробел или нет (ну и как следствие при отпускании пробела, кубик кидает туда, сколько оно натикало.

Проще добавить еще один счетчик (i++) в Udpate, который будет сдвигать кубик в более контролируемое время.

P.S. Из документации по функции:
*Regular (per frame) calls should be avoided: Time.time is intended to supply the length of time the application has been running for, and not the time per frame.*

Так что лучше не использовать данные часы в апдейте.

P.P.S И если добавлять туда счетчик, то движение лучше проводить в FixedUpdate, он, в отличие от Update, не зависит от FPS)